# Lost my Ubuntu created files by booting Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ntfs

I had created on Ubuntu a couple of directories on an NTFS partition, so far so good. Then I booted Windows 10 and when I tried accessing the the first one I got a message "file system corrupt and unreadable" or something like that, and I clicked the second one (bad move I know).

After booting Ubuntu I found that both of the directories disappeared. I've got a backup but I won't be back home until the weekend so I need a way to recover them.

PS: It still indicates that the space is used.
PS2: I tried 'ntfsfix' and 'TestDisk' and nothing seems to work. Recuva detects some files but the majority is still missing.

Comment: "Recuva detects some files but the majority is still missing." - Based on this evidence it sounds like your files are gone forever.

Comment: Thought so, I just had hope. Ok, I'll have to spend the week without them. Thanks